# not able to place the image at the center

Tags: angularjs, html, css

The image keep changing for every click of button. now the problem is i need to make the image center so that if the image is small or big it stay at the center and i have given the image responsive according to the height and width.

[image] 
currently this is at the center top i need it in the middle.

```
<section class="col col-2">
  <div class="imagewh">
    <center>
      <img type="image" data-ng-src="{{curIcon}}" ng-click="icon()" 
                       class="responsive" />
    </center>
  </div>
</section>  
.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}    
.imagewh {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
}
```

i am using angularjs, not able to find the solution please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flexbox:

```css
.imagewh {
    position: relative;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagewh">
  <img src="https://cataas.com/cat" width="20" height="20" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris" class="center">

.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}
```

This should centre it.

Answer (score 0):

```
.imagewh{
text-align:center;
width: 110px;
height: 110px;
}
.imagewh img{
position:relative;
top:50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}


<div class="imagewh">
   <img type="image" data-ng-src="{{curIcon}}" ng-click="icon()" class="responsive" />
 </div>
```

Please check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j0txnq3w/1/). Make sure you are adding browser prefix for transform property.

Answer (score 0):

this can be achived by using either flex, translate or table-cell of css3.

below is the example by using translate,

```css
.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -otransform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.imagewh {
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagewh">
  <img src="https://cataas.com/cat" width="20" height="20" class="responsive" />
</div>
```